# Entanglement of 3-qubit states

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, quantum-computation

Given a separable 3-qubit state

φ = φ<sub>0</sub> ⊗ φ<sub>1</sub> ⊗ φ<sub>2</sub>

with

φ<sub>i</sub>= a<sub>i0</sub>|0> + a<sub>i1</sub>|1>,

|0>, |1> being the computational base. φ thus can be written as

φ = b<sub>000</sub>|000> + b<sub>001</sub>|001> + b<sub>010</sub>|010> + b<sub>011</sub>|011> + b<sub>100</sub>|100> + b<sub>101</sub>|101> + b<sub>110</sub>|110> + b<sub>111</sub>|111>

with

|ijk> = |i> ⊗ |j> ⊗ |k>

b<sub>ijk</sub> = a<sub>0i</sub>a<sub>1j</sub>a<sub>2k</sub>.

---

Now let some b<sub>ijk</sub> be given, defining an arbitrary 3-qubit state

φ = b<sub>000</sub>|000> + b<sub>001</sub>|001> + b<sub>010</sub>|010> + b<sub>011</sub>|011> + b<sub>100</sub>|100> + b<sub>101</sub>|101> + b<sub>110</sub>|110> + b<sub>111</sub>|111>

### Question 1

How is Schmidt decomposition to be applied to the tensor B = (b<sub>ijk</sub>) to find out if the state is separable?

### Question 2

Assuming that the following five possibilities of entanglement are possible

1. φ<sub>0</sub>, φ<sub>1</sub> and φ<sub>2</sub> entangled,
2. φ<sub>i</sub> separable, φ<sub>j</sub> and φ<sub>k</sub> entangled,
3. φ<sub>0</sub>, φ<sub>1</sub> and φ<sub>2</sub> separable,

how do I calculate the corresponding coefficients, i.e. in case (3)

φ = φ<sub>0</sub> ⊗ φ<sub>1</sub> ⊗ φ<sub>2</sub>.

where I want to know the six coefficients a<sub>ij</sub> in

φ<sub>i</sub>= a<sub>i0</sub>|0> + a<sub>i1</sub>|1>.

Comment: Tripartite Schmidt decomposition is [not always possible](https://www.univie.ac.at/physikwiki/images/4/4e/QI_Sheet9.pdf) and [not easy when it is](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9911073).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint, it helps me a lot. But could you help me one step further: Why doesn't it help to consider the tripartite Hilbert space  H0 ⊗ H1 ⊗ H2 as a bipartite one: H0 ⊗ (H1 ⊗ H2) or (H0 ⊗ H1) ⊗ H2? (How would BTW the third possiblilty of decomposition to be spelled out?)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Do you know where I can find the solutions to or discussions of the Vienna exercises?

Comment: Assume that I let go three pure states φ0 ⊗ φ1 ⊗ φ2 through a CCNOT or a CSWAP gate. How do I know how the outgoing state is entangled?

Comment: I don't know where to find the solutions. As for the first question, the punch line is that there is information in the triple tensor product decomposition that can't be expressed in those terms alone

Comment: I'll think about the third comment